# Character Encoding in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file, encoding, file-io

I have exported excel 2007 document as CSV (separated by semicolon). I am using CZECH office 2010 and czech windows 7.

When i read file in .net C#, text with special czech symbols is corrupted. It is when i am using

something like string[] lines = file.readalllines(path); (from System.IO.File)

So i guess i need to specially provide right encoding, right? so i tried:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path,encoding);
```

encoding variable was defined like

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8 for example.
```

None of options worked. And strangest thing, some of them, like Encoding.Unicode even threw

```
IndexOutOfRandgeException
```

.

How should i fix this encoding problem? Thank you.

BTW, my office manages to open and read that document right way.

Comment: You'll have to find out and tell us _how_ those chech chars are encoded (stored) in the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably the encoding Excel writes your file is the default encoding of your system, which should be windows-1250. Either open your file with `Encoding.Default` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")`. It works for us here in Poland. I don't remember any issues regaring csvs exported from office.

Comment: Thank, you it is indeed 1250, and for some reason i thought it is 1251. Now it works with> Encoding.GetEncoding(1250). However, when it is default encoding, whould not work File.ReadAllLines(path), which should use default encoding? And any ideas about that indexoutofbounds? thank you.

Comment: Have no idea. It could be that your system is not Czech Windows or something. On Polish Windows, `Encoding.Default` and `Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)` returns the same encoding.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(path)` does not use `Encoding.Default` despite the possibly misleading name; it uses `Encoding.UTF8`.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember hitting this a couple of years ago with CSV exported from office excel

Googling on the web it seems that office will use different encodings depending on your version of office and you region.

In my case I believe the correct encoding was something weird like UTF7 (wtf) so try that. Otherwise you may be stuck trying every encoding until it decodes properly

The other option is to look for tools designed to detect the encoding of a file and run it over your input to determine the encoding